# Large number of authentication requests and then 0x8000FFFF error trying to access OneNote page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, single-sign-on, onenote, live-sdk

I'm following along with this OneNote API tutorial that uses the Live Connect SDK for Windows Phone 8 to authenticate the user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575424.aspx

I have authentication working but I'm seeing a strange workflow and then an error.

When I run the app on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator:

- I see the sign-in page. I click on the sign-in page to login with my Microsoft account.
- After I log in I am asked to authorize (my) app for access.  I click *yes* to do so and the page in my app prints out "authentication successful"
- I click the "Create simple page" button and it says "page successfully created"
- I click the "See page" button and it takes me to Microsoft's OneDrive where I need to sign in *again*.

At this point I get an error that says "Problem signing in. with the error code **0x8000FFFF**"

*Note: If I run it on my Lumia phone I don't get the error but when it tries to the view the page it says "Notebook not found" and aborts*.

*Note2: If I try to login to OneDrive directly via the home page I get an "HTTP 503 Service Unavailable" error.*

My questions are:

- How can I fix this error?  Is it simply not possible to effectively do an app like this in the Emulator?
- How can I streamline this authentication process?  I don't want to have to go through all the steps again every time I test my app, let alone how it will affect my users.  Is there a way to store involved authentication tokens and pass them back to both the Live SDK single-sign in control and to the web browser based *OneDrive* login?

**UPDATE #1**: Apparently developing Live connect apps with OneDrive login on the Emulator isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are hitting is related to the emulator. The emulator does not support opening the link that is returned.

If you run this on a device, it should open the note without any other auth requests assuming you used the same account that is logged in on the device.

Comment: Yes I updated my post a while ago when Ginny Caughey told me that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an issue with the Windows Phone emulator where it is not able to associate itself with a Microsoft Account. You can either try on your physical device, or you can also run the now free Windows desktop client (download it from http://www.onenote.com/Download) to see what the created page looks like.

We will update the sample readme to let folks know that they can't use the WP emulator to view the page. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I've posted a new problem report on the OneNote blog.  Should I be posting those here on SO with a OneNote tag instead? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/03/17/welcome-to-the-onenote-service-api.aspx

Comment: Yes, it would be easier for us to make sure your question gets answered if you post on StackOverflow here.

Comment: Will do. What about feature requests and the like?  Do you have a user voice for OneNote yet?  Or should I just use the blog.